# How to append hyperlink to replaceAllText command in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-slides-api

Basing a script off of this tutorial - https://spreadsheet.dev/convert-each-row-google-sheets-into-slide-google-slides-apps-script, works perfectly fine. However I'm trying to populate a hyperlink as part of the script, i.e in my script

```
slide.replaceAllText("{{projectName}}", row[0]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{userStory}}", row[1]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{POC}}", row[2]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{stakeholderName}}", row[3]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{brief}}", row[4]);
```

"brief" in column 5 on my spreadsheet is a URL, and I'd like to have it not appear as the URL in my slide deck but as a hyperlink on the word "Brief".

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to replace `{{brief}}` with the text of `Brief` with the hyperlink of `row[4]` on a slide in Google Slides.

In this case, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
slide.replaceAllText("{{brief}}", row[4]);
```

#### To:

```
slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
  const text = shape.getText();
  if (text.asString().includes("{{brief}}")) {
    text.setText("Brief").getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(row[4]);
  }
});
```

- By this modification, a shape including a text of `{{brief}}` is replaced with the text of `Brief` with the hyperlink of `row[4]`.

#### Reference:

- [setLinkUrl(url) of Class TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setLinkUrl(String))

Comment: @sixfiveoh About `This is perfect - thank you so much!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer